# Mongoose find/project in a complex structure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I got a problem with finding lines in a structure made of objects and arrays.

Here is my mongoose schema :

```
var subscriberSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    chkpt: {
        subDocs:[
            {
                id: String,
                newValues: {
                    attributes:[
                        {
                            _id: {
                                name: String
                            },
                            value: [
                                {
                                    string: String
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ] 
    }
});
```

And here is the request i try to apply on that schema :

```
Subscriber.find({'chkpt.modifiedSubDocs.newValues.attributes.id.name':'blabla'}, 'chkpt.modifiedSubDocs.newValues.attributes.value.string', function (err, subscribers) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        // Prints the json
        res.json(subscribers);
```

The problem is that the returned json contains every attributes arrays that contains at least one "blabla" in its ids.
I would like it to return only the value that corresponds to the line of 'attributes' array which has the id named "blabla".

If you know a method to do that, don't hesitate ;)

Thanks,

Bowbow

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `$` placement operator, in your projection, try to put `chkpt.subDocs.$.newValues.attributes.$.value.string`

Comment: Unfortunately i get an error when i had the $ placement operators.

ReferenceError: handleError is not defined

Comment: I don't really know Mongoose, but I think you need to put braces for the projection like `Subscriber.find({'chkpt.subDocs.newValues.attributes.id.name':'blabla'}, {'chkpt.subDocs.$.newValues.attributes.$.value.string'}, function())`

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it doesn't work with braces :(

Comment: I see that you have put `modifiedSubDocs` while in your schema the field is named `subDocs`. Did you modified your query to match the right field name ?

Comment: Yes i renamed the field when i wrote the topic, but i forgot to rename it in  the query...

Comment: In fact, what i really want my request to do is : finding all the chkpt/subDocs/newValues/attributes/value/string that have chkpt/subDocs/newValues/attributes/ = 'blabla'